# Source cannot not be null on thymeleaf page

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I have an exception (cannot be null)that is thrown when I fill in the email field of my form.  It happens when I submit my form.
I join the controller, model, service, and dto classes.

Controller class is:

```
@Controller
public class AdminController {

    @Autowired
    BusReservationService busReservationService;

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @GetMapping(value = { "/", "/login" })
    public ModelAndView login(@RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
            @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView= new ModelAndView("login");

        if (error !=null) {
            modelAndView.addObject("error", "Invalid Username and password!");
        }
        
        if (logout !=null) {
            modelAndView.addObject("message", "You're been logout out successfully.");
        }
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/signup")
    public ModelAndView signup() {

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("signup");
        modelAndView.addObject("adminSignupFormData", new AdminSignupFormCommand());

        return modelAndView;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/signup")
    public ModelAndView createNewAdminUser(
            @Valid @ModelAttribute("adminSignupFormData") AdminSignupFormCommand adminSignupFormCommand,
            BindingResult result) {

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("signup");

        if (result.hasErrors()) {

            return modelAndView;

        } else {
            try {
                UserDto newUser = registerAdmin(adminSignupFormCommand);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                result.rejectValue("email", "error.adminSignupFormCommand", e.getMessage());
                return modelAndView;
            }
        }

        return new ModelAndView("login");

    }

    private UserDto registerAdmin(@Valid AdminSignupFormCommand adminSignupFormCommand) {

        UserDto userDto = new UserDto()
                .setEmail(adminSignupFormCommand.getEmail())
                .setFirstName(adminSignupFormCommand.getFirstName())
                .setLastName(adminSignupFormCommand.getLastName())
                .setPassword(adminSignupFormCommand.getPassword())
                .setMobileNumber(adminSignupFormCommand.getMobileNumber())
                .setAdmin(true);
        UserDto admiDto = userService.signup(userDto);
        AgencyDto agencyDto = new AgencyDto().setDetails(adminSignupFormCommand.getAgencyDetails())
                .setName(adminSignupFormCommand.getAgencyName()).setUserOwner(admiDto);
        busReservationService.addAgency(agencyDto);
        return admiDto;
    }
    
    @GetMapping(value = {"/logout"})
    private String logout() {
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
        return "redirect:login";
        
    }
    
    @GetMapping(value = "/home")
    public String home() {
        
        return "redirect:dashboard";
    }
}
```

The page is :

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Sign Up</title>
<!-- Favicon icon -->
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">

<!-- Font Icon -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="/auth/fonts/material-icon/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css">

<!-- Main css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/auth/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="main">
        <!-- Sign up form -->
        <section class="signup">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="signup-content">
                    <div class="signup-form">
                        <h2 class="form-title">Sign up</h2>
                        <form action="#" method="POST" class="register-form"
                            id="register-form" th:action="@{/signup}"
                            th:object="${adminSignupFormData}">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="firstName"><i
                                    class="zmdi zmdi-account material-icons-name"></i></label> <input
                                    type="text" th:field="*{firstName}" name="firstName"
                                    id="firstName" placeholder="First Name" /> <small
                                    class="text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('firstName')}"
                                    th:errors="*{firstName}"></small>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="lastName"><i class="zmdi zmdi-account-o"></i></label>
                                <input type="text" th:field="*{lastName}" name="lastName"
                                    id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" /> <small
                                    class="text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('lastName')}"
                                    th:errors="*{lastName}"></small>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email"><i class="zmdi zmdi-email"></i></label> <input
                                    type="email" th:field="*{email}" name="email" id="email"
                                    placeholder="Your Email" /> <small class="text-danger"
                                    th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}" th:errors="*{email}">Email
                            Error</small>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="password"><i class="zmdi zmdi-lock"></i></label> <input
                                    type="password" th:field="*{password}" name="password"
                                    id="password" placeholder="Password" /> <small
                                    class="text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('password')}"
                                    th:errors="*{password}"></small>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="agencyName"><i class="zmdi zmdi-layers"></i></label>
                                <input type="text" th:field="*{agencyName}" name="agencyName"
                                    id="agencyName" placeholder="Agency Name" /> <small
                                    class="text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('agencyName')}"
                                    th:errors="*{agencyName}"></small>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="agencyDetails"><i
                                    class="zmdi zmdi-assignment"></i></label> <input type="text"
                                    th:field="*{agencyDetails}" name="agencyDetails"
                                    id="agencyDetails" placeholder="Agency Details" /> <small
                                    class="text-danger"
                                    th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('agencyDetails')}"
                                    th:errors="*{agencyDetails}"></small>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="mobileNumber"><i class="zmdi zmdi-phone"></i></label>
                                <input type="text" th:field="*{mobileNumber}"
                                    name="mobileNumber" id="mobileNumber"
                                    placeholder="Contact Number" /> <small class="text-danger"
                                    th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('mobileNumber')}"
                                    th:errors="*{mobileNumber}"></small>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="agree-term" id="agree-term"
                                    class="agree-term" /> <label for="agree-term"
                                    class="label-agree-term"><span><span></span></span>I
                                    agree all statements in <a href="#" class="term-service">Terms
                                        of service</a></label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group form-button">
                                <input type="submit" name="signup" id="signup"
                                    class="form-submit" value="Register" />
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="signup-image">
                        <figure>
                            <img src="/auth/images/signup-image.jpg" alt="sing up image">
                        </figure>
                        <a href="/login" class="signup-image-link">I am already member</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>

    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="/auth/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The  service class is:

```
@Component
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDto signup(UserDto userDto) {

        Role userRole;

        User userOptional = userRepository.findByEmail(userDto.getEmail());

        if (userOptional == null) {

            if (userDto.isAdmin()) {

                userRole = roleRepository.findByRole(UserRole.ADMIN);
            } else {
                userRole = roleRepository.findByRole(UserRole.PASSENGER);
            }
            userOptional= new User().setEmail(userDto.getEmail()).setFirstName(userDto.getFirstName())
                    .setLastName(userDto.getLastName()).setMobileNumber(userDto.getMobileNumber())
                    .setPassword(userDto.getPassword()).setRoles(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(userRole)));

            return UserMapper.userDto(userRepository.save(userOptional));
        }
        throw exception(EntityType.USER, ExceptionType.DUPLICATE_ENTITY, userDto.getEmail());
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDto findUserByEmail(String email) {

        Optional<User> usOptional = Optional.ofNullable(userRepository.findByEmail(email));

        if (usOptional.isPresent()) {

            return modelMapper.map(usOptional.get(), UserDto.class);
        }
        throw exception(EntityType.USER, ExceptionType.ENTITY_NOT_FOUND, email);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDto updteProfile(UserDto userDto) {

        Optional<User> uOptional = Optional.ofNullable(userRepository.findByEmail(userDto.getEmail()));

        if (uOptional.isPresent()) {

            User user = uOptional.get().setEmail(userDto.getEmail()).setFirstName(userDto.getFirstName())
                    .setLastName(userDto.getLastName()).setMobileNumber(userDto.getMobileNumber());

            return UserMapper.userDto(userRepository.save(user));
        }

        throw exception(EntityType.USER, ExceptionType.ENTITY_NOT_FOUND, userDto.getEmail());
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDto changePassword(UserDto userDto, String newPassword) {

        Optional<User> userChangepassword = Optional.ofNullable(userRepository.findByEmail(userDto.getEmail()));

        if (userChangepassword.isPresent()) {

            User password = userChangepassword.get().setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(newPassword));
            return UserMapper.userDto(userRepository.save(password));

        }

        throw exception(EntityType.USER, ExceptionType.ENTITY_NOT_FOUND, userDto.getEmail());
    }

    /**
     * @param entityType
     * @param exceptionType
     * @param arg
     * @return
     */
    private RuntimeException exception(EntityType entityType, ExceptionType exceptionType, String... arg) {

        return BSRExecption.throwException(entityType, exceptionType, arg);

    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<UserDto> getAllUsers() {

        return StreamSupport.stream(userRepository.findAll().spliterator(), false).distinct()
                .map(users -> (modelMapper.map(users, UserDto.class))).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
    }

}
```

and finally the  mapper class of dto is:

```
@Component
public class UserMapper {

    public static UserDto userDto(User user) {
        return new UserDto().setEmail(user.getEmail()).setFirstName(user.getFirstName())
                .setLastName(user.getLastName()).setMobileNumber(user.getMobileNumber())
                .setRolesDtos(new HashSet<RoleDto>(user.getRoles().stream()
                        .map(role -> new ModelMapper().map(role, RoleDto.class)).collect(Collectors.toSet())));

    }
}
```

this a screen of  signup page:

[image]

The model class:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "bankass", name = "users", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
        "users_id" }), indexes = @Index(columnList = "email", name = "idx_users_email", unique = true))
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Slf4j
@Getter
@Setter
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class User implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "users_id")
    private long id;

    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "first_name", updatable = true)
    @NotBlank
    @NotEmpty(message = "First name is required")
    private String firstName;

    //@NonNull
    @Column(name = "last_name", updatable = true)
    @NotBlank
    @NotEmpty(message = "Last name is required")
    private String lastName;

    @NonNull
    @Column
    @Email
    @NotBlank
    @NotEmpty(message = " email is required")
    private String email;

    @NonNull
    @Column
    @NotBlank
    @NotEmpty(message = " password  is required")
    private String password;

    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "mobile_number", updatable = true)
    @NotBlank
    @NotEmpty(message = " mobile number is required")
    /*
     * @Pattern(regexp="^\\(?(\\d{3})\\)?[- ]?(\\d{3})[- ]?(\\d{4})$",
     * message="Mobile number is invalid")
     */
    private String mobileNumber;

    // User role
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(schema = "bankass", name = "users_role", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "users_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "role_id") })
    private Set<Role> roles;

    public String getFullName() {
        return firstName != null ? firstName.concat("").concat("lastName") : "";

    }
}
```

The custom security class is:

```
@Configuration("CustomSecurityConfig")
```

@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class MultiHttpSecurityConfig {

```
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private  BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    
    @Autowired
    private  CustomuserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builderAuth) throws Exception {
        builderAuth.userDetailsService(this.userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable().antMatcher("/api/*").authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/v1/user/signup")
                .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint((req, rsq, e) -> rsq.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED)).and()
                .addFilter(new ApiJWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilter(new ApiJWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager())).sessionManagement()
                // This diseables session creation on Spring Security
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService usDetailsService() {
        return new CustomuserDetailsService();

    }
    
      @Bean(name = "pwdEncoder") public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
      DelegatingPasswordEncoder delPasswordEncoder = (DelegatingPasswordEncoder)
      PasswordEncoderFactories .createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
      BCryptPasswordEncoder bcryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
      delPasswordEncoder.setDefaultPasswordEncoderForMatches(bcryptPasswordEncoder)
      ; return delPasswordEncoder; }
     

}

/*
 * @Bean public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
 * 
 * final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new
 * UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
 * 
 * CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new
 * CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues();
 * source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration); return source; }
 */

@Configuration
@Order(2)
public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    private CustomAuthentionSuccesshandler customAuthentionSuccesshandler;
    private CustomuserDetailsService customuserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter(BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder,
            CustomAuthentionSuccesshandler customAuthentionSuccesshandler,
            CustomuserDetailsService customuserDetailsService) {
        super();
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
        this.customAuthentionSuccesshandler = customAuthentionSuccesshandler;
        this.customuserDetailsService = customuserDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
        builder.userDetailsService(customuserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/signup").permitAll().antMatchers("/dashbord/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN").anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .usernameParameter("email").passwordParameter("password")
                .successHandler(customAuthentionSuccesshandler).and().logout().permitAll()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessHandler(new CustomLogoutSuccessHandler()).deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and().exceptionHandling();

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) throws Exception {

        webSecurity.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/js/**", "/images/**",
                "/resources/static/**", "/css/**", "/im/**", "/fonts/**", "/images/**", "/scss/**", "/vendor/**",
                "/favicon.ico", "/auth/**", "/favicon.png", "/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/ui",
                "/configuration/security", "/webjars/**", "/swagger-resources/**", "/actuator", "/swagger-ui/**",
                "/swagger-ui/index.html", "/swagger-ui/");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Can you add the full stacktrace?

Comment: Hello,  I add the stacktrace.

Comment: That is not a stacktrace, but a log. :) In any case, I don't see any exception in what you posted.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your help, indeed, I don't find any exception raised in the logs when I fill in all the mandatory fields of the form and submit it in the postgres database. That's why I asked for help on the subject. I have a return code 200, and if I look in the database, no data is inserted.

Comment: Is the form error thrown after the `No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder' available` exception has been fixed (spring-security-core missing from classpath)?